# Появляется ошибка при попытке установить mysqlclient

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Появляется данная ошибка при попытке установить mysqlclient. visual studio и компоненты для Python установлены. Python 3.8

```
ERROR:Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\minutex\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f1qh8zuj\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f1qh8zuj\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install —record 'C:\Users\MinuteX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dkysvbzn\install-record.txt' —single-version-externally-managed —compile
cwd: C:\Users\MinuteX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f1qh8zuj\mysqlclient\
Complete output (24 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
—------------------------------------—
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\minutex\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f1qh8zuj\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MinuteX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f1qh8zuj\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'&quo
```

Comment: *Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required* - что в этой фразе непонятно?

Comment: Я же написал что он установлен

Comment: и даже запущен.

Comment: Если инсталлятор считает, что нет - то он прав. Или не установлено, или криво установлено, или установлено, да не то, хоть названия и похожи.  Впрочем, всё одно его не переспоришь. Так что сноси что есть и ставь заново, строго по науке, чтобы ни ошибок, ни предупреждений, и не забудь проверить, что ставишь строго то, что требуется.

Comment: Скачал и установил Visual Studio 14.0 и переустановил 4 раза, но инсталлятор все равно ругается на его отсутствие

Comment: А точно вместе с *"Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"*?

Comment: Как проверить?,

Comment: Понятия не имею. По сообщению об ошибке материалов достаточно, в т.ч. есть и ссылки на репозитарии. Полазь, посмотри...

Comment: Проще скачать [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) прекомпилированную версию.

Comment: Сделал, спасибо